# Why are the ILT and IAT separate tables?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, portable-executable, malware, internals

I am learning about the PE format, specifically about the design of imports, and I have a question about the design of the IAT and ILT. why do they need to be separate tables?
To my understanding, they are identical on disk, and when the PE is loaded to memory, each entry in the IAT is replaced by the loader to the actual address of the imported function. [PE format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#delay-import-address-table):

> "The structure and content of the import address table are identical to those of the import lookup table, until the file is bound. During binding, the entries in the import address table are overwritten with the 32-bit (for PE32) or 64-bit (for PE32+) addresses of the symbols that are being imported."

my question is:
why can't this be done to the ILT instead? instead of having two tables, remove one table, lets say we remove the IAT: so now when the PE is loaded the entries of the ILT are replaced by the actual addresses, and we save space by not having the IAT.

I've been trying to think of a need to save the values of the ILT during execution but can't think of nothing. I'm sure there is a rational behind this design. I've read the "PE format" article on msdn, various blogs and answers on here but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: If you combine the IAT and ILT and the binding fails, how would you know what function the bind was for, so you can rebind it at load time?

Comment: Sorry for the deleting my comment, I was trying to edit it. let me ask again please, Isn’t the loader pre fills the IAT then? because on disk there is no prediction.

Comment: There *is* prediction on disk. That's what binding is: Making a prediction and saving it back to disk.

Comment: @RaymondChen In the case in which the loader uses one table, wouldn't the loader save the function it bound somewhere so that it couldn't bind it again?

Comment: @RaymondChen I understand you are talking specifically about bound imports? if so, is it the only reason you need to split the tables? because otherwise the tables are identical

Comment: @Ori If you bind by using `BindImage`, the PE header of the image file will be changed. I understand the timestamps and DLL name, etc. are also written to `IMAGE_BOUND_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` of the image file. Thus, the loader can determine if it should use IAT.

Comment: "wouldn't the loader save the function it bound somewhere..." The loader doesn't do binding. Binding happens to the binary on disk. After binding, the IAT holds the bound addresses and the ILT contains the names of the functions before they were bound. This is what the quoted paragraph is saying. It is therefore not always the case that the IAT and ILT are identical.

Comment: @couyoh Thanks, I do know bound imports, I think it was important to specify we were talking about these imports, as I see BindImage and binding are concepts specific for bound imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *bind* by using `BindImage` API. According to [`BindImageEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-bindimageex):

> The process of binding an image consists of computing the virtual address of each imported function. The computed virtual address is then saved in the importing image's Import Address Table (IAT). As a result, the image is loaded much faster, particularly if it uses many DLLs, because the system loader does not have to compute the address of each imported function.

Therefore, I think it's because the binding rewrites the IAT to the actual address **before** being loaded by the loader.
If the DLL is updated, and the actual address is changed, uses ILT. That's why they have ILT and IAT, I understand.

Comment: Cool! one last thing - are bound imports not deprecated? ASLR pretty much makes them useless, and I never encountered a binary that uses them. I think it’s quite weird to have a separate table for a feature thats rarely used

Comment: @e.biran I don't know whether it's deprecated or not. FYI, some linker has an option not to generate IAT. For example, MSVC Linker is possible by [`/delay:nobind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls#bind-delay-loaded-imports).